# Reactjs - `component` vs `render` in Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I have two doubts regarding usage of `Route` from `react-router-dom`(**v4.3.1**):

1. When do we use `component` vs `render` in `Route`:

   ```
   <Route exact path='/u/:username/' component={ProfileComponent} />
   <Route exact path='/u/:username/' render={() => <ProfileComponent />} />
   ```
2. How to access the variable `username` in the **URL** in both ways?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you pass a component to the `component` prop, the component will get the path parameters in the `props.match.params` object, i.e `props.match.params.username` in your example:

```
class ProfileComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.match.params.username}</div>;
  }
}
```

When using the `render` prop, the path parameters can be accessed through the props given to the `render` function:

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/u/:username/'
  render={(props) => 
    <ProfileComponent username={props.match.params.username}/>
  }
/>
```

You generally use the `render` prop when you need some data from the component that contains your routes, since the `component` prop gives no real way of passing in additional props to the component.

Comment: The last sentence is the key part that every other explanation of this leaves out. Thank you!